# Why is my AJAX code only paritially working?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Hello people here is my code

```
echo('Name: <input type="text" id="Name" onchange="im()" value="your name"  name="Name" />');
echo('pointsize: <input type="text" id="pointsize" onchange="im()" value="50" name="pointsize" />');
echo('format: <input type="text" id="format" value=".gif" onchange="im()" name="format" />');
echo('BackGround Color: <input type="text" id="bckclr" value="red" onchange="im()" name="bckclr" />');
echo('FontColor: <input type="text" id="color" value="white" onchange="im()" name="color" />');
echo('Border Color: <input type="text" id="bcolor" value="blue" onchange="im()" name="bcolor" />');
echo('<a href="./lang/ims.php"><img src="'.$image.'" height="82" width="82" /></a>');
echo('Font: <input type="text" id="font" value="'.$image1.'" onchange="im()" name="font" />');

echo ('<div id="Div_Im">');
echo('replace me');
echo ('</div>');
```

Here is my AJAX code.

```
<Script type="text/javascript">
    function im()
    {
        var Name=document.getElementById("Name").value;
        var pointsize=document.getElementById("pointsize").value;
        var format=document.getElementById("format").value;
        var bckclr=document.getElementById("bckclr").value;
        var color=document.getElementById("color").value;
        var bcolor=document.getElementById("bcolor").value;
        var font=document.getElementById("font").value;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var url='Name='+Name+'&pointsize='+pointsize+'&format='+format+'&bckclr='+bckclr+'&color='+color+'&bcolor='+bcolor+'&font='+font;
            alert(url);
            //-----Sending request to server for getting job name list by ajax-----
            $.ajax({
                type    : "POST",
                url : "i.php?",
                data    : url,              
                cache   : false,
                success : function(html)
                {
                    //document.getElementById('Div_PJobId').style.display="block";
                    //alert('hi');
                    alert(html);
                    var pic='<img src="'+html+'">';
                    $("#Div_Im").html(pic).show();
                }
            });
        });
     }
</script>
```

And here is my server page code for i.php

```
$Name=$_POST["Name"];
$pointsize=$_POST["pointsize"];
$bckclr=$_POST["bckclr"];
$color=$_POST["color"];
$bcolor=$_POST["bcolor"];
$format=$_POST["format"];
//$filename = "./lang/sri".$format;
$filename = "./lang/".$Name.$format;
$font=$_POST["font"]; 

$cmd = " -background $bckclr -pointsize $pointsize -font $font -fill $color ".
            " -strokewidth 1 -stroke $bcolor label:\"$Name\" ";

exec("convert $cmd $filename");
//if($filename)
//{}
//echo('<img src="'.$filename.'">');
echo $filename;
```

Please check the [demo link](http://ultimateweblogos.com/im.php). Contents(image shown in ) of  is replacing only if I make changes to name ,but it does not work for color,bcolor,font,...I need to refresh the page every time when I make changes.... is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: It seems I have already seen this question today.

Comment: thats not the compleate question

Comment: Then you could have edited that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was debugging your code and found that every thing is working fine on client side as on every change(in input ) you are calling to your server with latest data and replacing your image based on html you get from server.

I believe there is problem to your server side code. as I saw you are assigning name to created image file using name field value. it means name image file already created for color change as name is already provided. you should look your server side code. some time response is taking infinite time to return from server.

Comment: hmmm that could be the reason but how to fix this?i was running the same code on my localhost...i had the sme issue... i have also shown my server side code... is there a way to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

1. You've wrapped `$(document).ready` function inside the `im()` function.. why is that?
2. Why didn't you used jQuery for getting the inputs values?

   ```
   function im() { 

   $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST", 
      url: "i.php?", 
      data: {
            Name:$('#Name').val(), 
            pointsize:$('#pointsize').val(),
            format:$('#format').val(),
            bckclr:$('#bckclr').val(),
            color:$('#color').val(),
            bcolor:$('#bcolor').val(),
            font:$('#font').val()   
      },               
      cache: false
   }).done(function(html) { 

           //document.getElementById('Div_PJobId').style.display="block"; 
           //alert('hi'); 
           alert(html); 
           var pic='<img src="'+html+'">'; 
           $("#Div_Im").html(pic).show(); 

   }); 
   }
   ```

Comment: You didn't changed the code in the link you gave us.. please make the chnages there because we want to test it

Comment: It's working for me.. `replace me` has been replaced with `<img src="./lang/your name.gif ">`. There is a delay but I think that this is caused by your php file which returns the results. After you change the content of an input you have to press enter or to blur it

Comment: nope.. iam checking on my localhost.its still not working..:(it works only if u change your name... but does not work for other features like color,backgrnd color,size.. and all... we might see a alert box.. but the image will will not change...